# Ember: how to bind HTML class to Service property, so that class is dynamic

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a parent `route`. Inside this route there is a component that is rendered.

The `route` has a `template.hbs` file that contains a HTML div element. I need to be able to change the class of this div element from within my child `component`.

To do this, I was planning on using a service. The idea being inject the service into both the `route` and child `component` and then bind the class of the div to a property on the service. Then, when I inject the service into the child component I can change the property and see any changes reflected by the parent route.

Problem is, the binding doesn't seem to work!

Parent Route:

Template:
`<div class={{model.containerClass}}>`

Route.js:

```
dashboardContainerManager: service('dashboard-container-manager'),

afterModel(model) {
   model.set('containerClass', this.get('dashboardContainerManager').dashboardContainerClass);
```

SERVICE:

```
export default Service.extend({
  dashboardContainerClass: null,

  init() {
    debugger; //placed to ensure one instance being made
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('dashboardContainerClass', 'container dashboard-container'); //need to set it here to prevent glimmer error
  },

  changeContainerClass(newClass) {
    debugger;
    this.set('dashboardContainerClass', newClass);
  }
});
```

Child Component:

```
  dashboardContainerManager: service('dashboard-container-manager'),
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('dashboardContainerManager').changeContainerClass('test');
  },
```

The result of the above code is that the class of my div is initially set to "container dashboard-container" because that's the value that the `dashboardContainerClass` property on my service is initialised to. However, when the value is changed to "test" inside my component, the class of my div isn't updated which suggests it's not bound properly to the value of `dashboardContainerClass`. I tried using a computed property in various places as well but couldn't get anything to work.

What am I doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `reads` computed property macro that'd help you out here:

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.7/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/reads

in your component, you'd just do something like:

```
import { reads } from '@ember/object/computed';

  // ...
  dashboardContainerManager: service('dashboard-container-manager'),

  containerClass: reads('dashboardContainerManager.dashboardContainerClass'),
```

#### Update / full example:

service:

```
export default Service.extend({
  dashboardContainerClass: 'container dashboard-container',

  changeContainerClass(newClass) {
    this.set('dashboardContainerClass', newClass);
  }
});
```

route:

```
export default Route.extend({
  // removed afterModel and service injection
});
```

controller:

```
export default Controller.extend({
  containerManager: service('dashboard-container-manager'),

  containerClass: reads('containerManager.dashboardContainerClass'),
});
```

template:

```
<div class='some-other-class {{containerClass}}'>
  other stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out. Do you mean to say inside my route.js (instead of in my component)?

Comment: ah! no, I mean inside a component or controller. A route's scope is different from the template scope.
Routes are just for managing routing events  / before/model/after hooks, so if you want to access anything from a route's corresponding template, it needs to be specified in the controller. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's why I've been setting the property on the model inside the afterModel() method...So that it can be accessed from the template . - p.s didn't work x((((((

Comment: ok, gotchya. The model won't update when the service property updates, but a computed property will.

The model only updates when a navigation or route param changes

Comment: I'll add some additional code for how I'd do the whole thing, one sec

Comment: Ah ok interesting so I would setting the model property to a computed property that watches the service property be solution? Or would the computed property not update because it's a property on the model

Comment: the model doesn't need to be a computed property, the model is just data that is passed down from the route's model hook, no need to mess with it from there. :)

I've updated my example to show where the service/reads stuff would go.

the model hook is designed to provide _data_ for the entire route, like.. API data retrieved via fetch, or ember-data (I don't know how much ember you know or don't know (sorry)) --- so keeping the model hook's return value pure data is ideal for data flow / debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187594/discussion-between-helloworld-and-nullvoxpopuli).